# using list for storing objects

Tags: c++, list

I want to know is it the right way or is there any proper way to store different objects of same class and use operations of the class?

```
class Camera_ {

//function1
//function2
//function3

}

int main()
{
    int n ;
    std::cout <<"\n How many Cameras you are using ? \n";
    std ::cin >> n;
    std:: cout << "The number of camera is " << n << std ::endl ;

    std::list<Camera_> list1; // creating a list of camera



    for(int j=0; j<n; j++) //transfer array
    camera = new Camera_;// camera object        
    list1.push_back( camera);// storing camera objects
    list<Camera_>::iterator it;
    for(it = iList.begin(); it != iList.end(); it++)
    *it->function1();
    *it->function2();
    *it->function3();  // I am trying to access 3 function of the class for each objects of camera class. 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For your need it may be efficient if you use `std::vector` instead `std::list`

Comment: I am not finding any proper example to use std::vector for storing different objects of the same class and doing operation on it, can you please give me a good resources, I have tried looking different question answers here, thank you for answering it .

Comment: Don't use a list of `Camera` pointers. You can just use a list (or vector if you don't plan on adding or removing from the middle of the list often) of `Camera` objects i.e. `std::list<Camera>`.

Comment: You find list tutorials [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/stl/stllist.html) or [here](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialC++STL.html) and all over the net. You can access the functions of a `Camera` by dereferencing an iterator, as you are doing.

Comment: Thank you for answering . In that case, if I want to have multiple objects of the same class, how would I do it?

Comment: Create a new `Camera_` in each loop and `push_back` it into the list. At present you are creating one `Camera_` before the loop and then either  pushing back uninitialized pointers or overrunning your array (if n > 10). Remove the `Camera_*` array, you don't need it (you have the std::list).

Answer (score 0):

What you showed is not proper.  It should look something more like this:

```
class Camera {
public:
    void function1() {
        // ...
    }
    void function2() {
        // ...
    }
    void function3() {
        // ...
    }
};

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cout << "How many Cameras you are using? ";
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cout << "The number of Cameras is " << n << std ::endl;

    std::list<Camera> list1; // creating a list of camera

    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
        list1.push_back( Camera() ); // storing camera objects
        // or, if using C++11 or later:
        // list1.emplace_back();
    }
    // or simply:
    // list1.resize(n);

    list<Camera>::iterator it;
    for(it = list1.begin(); it != list1.end(); ++it) {
        it->function1();
        it->function2();
        it->function3();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have understood now.  But this line should be like this list1.push_back( Camera );   why you are using Camera();

Comment: @FarialSamia: The `Camera()` is explicitly calling the constructor. On C++11, this will construct a temp object, move it into a new object in the `list`, then destruct the (now useless) temp object. Using `emplace_back` avoids the need to actually repeat the name of the class, and directly constructs into the `list`, avoiding any extraneous construction/destruction.

Answer (score 0):

Here'r some suggestions which may improve efficiency and other stuff :

1. If you are not doing frequent insertions at particular indexes, use vector instead of list, you will get random acces (This depends on you usecase).
2. Use smart pointer - you are storing pointer of Camera_ class

   camera = new Camera_;// camera object
   list1.push_back( camera);// storing camera objects

Change it to :

```
shared_ptr<Camera_> sptr = make_shared(new Camera_);
list1.push_back(sptr);// storing camera objects
```

It's a better practice to use smart pointers as you get away from the burden of deleting the memory. Using raw pointer may lead to memory leak even after proper care sometimes (for eg during exceptions).

Comment: @instace, thank you for your solution. If I use shared pointer, do I need to use custom delete for the shared pointer ? Another thing , what is the advantage of using vector here, can you give any example of doing this using vector.

Comment: If you using smart pointers, you don't need to specifically delete it as these are reference based pointers, will be deleted automatically as soon as reference count is zero. Secondly, container choice depends on your future use, like frequent insertions/deletions/search. Make a wise choice considering your usecase.